# jQuery select checks not working properly

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/Y7dcX/3/

Im trying to alert that one "timebox" can have a 0 value in both 2seats and 4seats selects.

This works fine almost, there's one little issue if you select a value in the 2seats in the second "timebox" (the one under the black border) and then select a value in the first "timebox"s 4seats, then press submit -> then it will still give error alert??

Comment: I just noticed how many thousands of questions on SO are about things "not working properly".

Answer (score 0):

Please Check your last raw of your html code .I see it like bellow.

```
</table></form>
```

It should like bellow

```
</form> </table>
```

Comment: While invalid HTML, this has nothing to do with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have the same error in two different places. Within your `.each()` statement, use `this` instead of referencing the class again. That's screwing up the retrieval of values.

Change:

```
if( $(this).val() == 0 && $('.seats_free_2tables').closest("tr").next().find('.seats_free_4tables').val() == 0 )
```

to

```
if( $(this).val() == 0 && $(this).closest("tr").next().find('.seats_free_4tables').val() == 0 )
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Y7dcX/4/)**

To put a fine point on it, change `$('.seats_free_2tables').closest("tr")` to `$(this ).closest("tr")` and `$('.seats_free_4tables').closest("tr").` to `$(this).closest("tr").`